# How does PHP count objects in multidimensional arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, count

While I was learning about a count function for arrays and looking at some examples I noticed something I don't understand. Can you clarify me the behavior in the example below.

I read how count function works in PHP manual and I know that the second parameter in function means that it will recursively count the array.

```
<?php
$fruits = array ("apple", "orange", array("pear" , "mango"), "banana");
echo (count($fruits,1));
```

So the result without 1 as the second parameter should be 4 and with it should be 5, yet I get 6 as the output.

Comment: 4 in the 1st level ( one of which is an array ) and 2 in the second level = 6??

Comment: It is the total number of keys in that array. The nested array is at key 2 of the parent array, so that still counts. 4 (parent) + 2 (child) = 6

Comment: So it adds +1 because it counts array as the element of parent array. Thank you for quick answers. I was confused because on one of the test from the previous years I saw 5 as the correct answer. Must have been teachers mistake than.

Answer (score 0):

```
$fruits = array("apple", "orange", array(), array("pear", "mango"), "banana");
echo (count($fruits, 1));
```

The answer is simple. The output of this code is 7.

```
1) apple
2) orange  
3) array() 
4) array() 
5) pear 
6) mongo 
7) banana
```

If I want to explain it accurately and simply:

```
<?php
$arr = ['a', 'b', array('c', 'd')];
$cnt = count($arr);
foreach($arr as $item) {
    if(is_array($item)) {
        $cnt += count($item);
    }
}
echo $cnt;
```